# The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-play-services

Whenever I try to run the Google Map API v2 project it shows the following error
"The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included."
Actually I was trying to add a marker to a specific location whenever clicked on a List Item but I don't see any markers instead I get the App stopped working message in the device. I then checked on the sdk manager and there was an update available for Google Play Services and I downloaded it but also the error is there. So please anyone help.

Comment: There is no real solution on that post you linked to.

Comment: same problem here, after last update. i'm using only +1 button. everything is working fine in the app, but i have this error + warnings in logcat.

Comment: @Ricardo like Igor said, your link doesn't contain a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same error in LogCat.  Everything was working fine, but it appears the cause of the error message for me was `setMyLocationEnabled()`

I removed that and stopped getting the error message but added it back because I need it.  It doesn't seem to be affecting my app negatively though.