# The Google Play services resources were not configured

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

**Before you read this, NOTICE:**

I have done my research and have read other questions like the following
[The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190412/the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-project-configurat)
and more,

**the error I get is:**

The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included

**I'm Using Eclipse**

**What they offered in other questions**

- updating all the packages & software
- adding the library to the Java Build Path (I am using Eclipse)
- using the Google API instead of the Android one (in project properties -> android)

none of these solutions seems to help, and I'm hoping maybe someone will have a better solution here

**What Service I am using**

I'm trying to use Google's GCM Service

so...anyone?

Comment: In the android build path under the Order & export tab have you exported the Google Play Services

Comment: Is this a real error i.e. does the app fail, or is it just the case that the error message is put out ? I am seeing this message on the emulator, but my app appears to function correctly.

Comment: I have the same issue. My app appears to function correctly, but if I decomment setMyLocationEnabled(true), I don't have that error anymore.I think the problem is that the LocationSerivce try to get the actual position, but the emulator can not get it

Answer (score 2):

It happened for me when Location Service is not able to get the current location by any means - and setMyLocationEnabled(true) is called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed the google library file in the location of your project file? Have you checked in the project properties that google play services library is included or not? Is it shows red cross before the googl play services library in properties dialog?

Comment: yes, I have included the google-play-services.jar in my java build path

Comment: Do you have gcm.jar in your libs folder under your project?