# The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm running into this problem from a few days now and I'm not able to find the solution. The fact is that the maps worked fine till few days ago.

I've done some research on Google and Stackoverflow and they offer these solutions:

- updating all the packages & software
- adding the library to the Java Build Path

I've read also this question: [The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190412/the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-project-configurat)

But none of these solutions have solved my problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you including the google-play-services_lib project as a library reference or just copying the jar into your project?

You need to make sure you are linking it as a library project for the Android resources to be copied into your project right.